# How re-map the shortcut key in terminal

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

According to the [Gnome-Termianl Usage](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/gnome-terminal-usage.html.en), I found that ctrl+shift+up/down can scroll up/down a line in the terminal.

Now, I want to re-map the shortcut key, just like: **shift+j/k** to **up/down** a line, that's the old habit of vimer. :) I tried searching the settings in **Edit** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts** of Terminal, but found nothing.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

---

The information of my computer:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.10 \n \l
```

Comment: map shift+j/k it not a good practice,you can't input J/K any more

Comment: J/K could be inputed by CapsLK

Comment: Alright, I think I can using alt+j/k to scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shortcuts by installing Advance keyboard shortcuts tool - gconf-editor (GConf-Editor)

You can install this tool by typing the following command :
 `sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`

Now run gconf-editor
 you can run is through the terminal by typing
`gconf-editor &`

--->Now double click the "apps" folder

--->Next double click the "metacity" folder

--->Finally click the global_keybindings folder

now you can change the value for next_tab and prev_tab. :)

Comment: I cannot found the **global_keybindings** folder under **metacity** foler. Only **general** folder is shown.